# Why APC's "cached files" jump so fast?

Tags: php, apc

It keeps jump :

```
Cached Files    292 ( 32.3 MBytes)

...

Cached Files 0 ( 0.0 Bytes)
```

Is that normal?

Why can't the figure be stable in production environment?

Comment: Could you provide more information about your project / diferences between dev and production or anything relevant?

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason for this could be that the cache is full. See this SO entry: [PHP APC: What happens when APC cache is full?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053810/php-apc-what-happens-when-apc-cache-is-full)

Try setting to cache size to 64MB or 128MB and have a look how much of the cache is used. If it's over 32MB then you may have to increase the cache size permanently.

Comment: You can see how much is being used with the 'apc.php' script that is copied with the main apc.so. On Ubuntu, it is at /usr/share/doc/php-apc/apc.php.gz

Answer (score 0):

Use the apc.php script to see the use of the memory. You should keep 20% of free memory (after hours).

Use apc.shm_size parameter to increase memory. Don't hesitate to give GB on large server.
If you cannot increase the segement size, increase the segment number.