# PHP script to be run at startup (APC variables initialization)

Tags: php, initialization, startup, apc

Is it possible to have the PHP server (via php5-fpm) run a PHP script just after it started, and before clients have access to it, in order to perform the initialization of [APC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.apc.php) variables.

Basically some events are counted during the server life via `apc_inc`, like

```
apc_inc('event-xyz-happened');
```

the *event-xyz-happened* APC var is permanent (life span is server life, not request life).

The problem is, the *event-xyz-happened* APC var has to exist before it is incremented (unlike Perl) the first time. `apc_inc` being pretty fast, I want to avoid solutions like

```
if ( ! apc_exists('event-xyz-happened')) {
  apc_store('event-xyz-happened', 1);
}
else {
  apc_inc('event-xyz-happened');
}
```

which not only require a call to `apc_exists('event-xyz-happened')`, but may also suffer from a race condition when it doesn't exist yet.

--

Is there a solution to create some APC variables before clients have access to the server?

Comment: dunno about php5-fpm but I know that at work we have the following in our virtual host config in apache which looks to achieve a similar thing to what you're after:
`php_value auto_prepend_file /var/www/xhprof_gui/xhprof_session.php`

Comment: @Jason this is to set configuration directives, not APC variables (plus, I'm using *nginx*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use apc_add followed by apc_inc (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-add.php)

```
// if it doesn't exist, it gets created
// if it does exist, nothing happens, no race condition
apc_add('event-xyz-happened', 0); 
apc_inc('event-xyz-happened', 1);
```

Comment: Good idea indeed. I'd still prefer an *initialization* solution, that would avoid the `apc_add` overhead. But that's the best alternative so far.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use apc variables for this purpose.

APC is a cache engine, it is not a fast database engine. 
As a cache engine, it can and it will sooner or later remove your variables to clear some memory for other variables or opcode cache. The more memory you assinge to APC the less probable it is that your variable will get removed, but you cannot rely that the variable will be there.

All your php scripts have to check if the variable is in apc cache, and if it is not, initialize it.

If you need to store some variables with very quick access, you can setup a local mysql server and create a table with 'memory' engine. It will be almost as fast as apc, but i will be permament, as long as the server is running.

Good luck
SWilk

Comment: This is not true. If no [*ttl*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-store.php) is specified, the variable will not expire (as long as there is memory available). As for creating a *memory* table in a DB, I'm after performance, and I doubt an inc+query+fetch... from a database can be even close to `apc_inc` (which returns the incremented value) in terms of performance.

Comment: I am just saying that you cannot rely on the variable beeing in cache for sure. If you run out of memory and no variable ttl has run out then entire cache will be purged. See 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053810/php-apc-what-happens-when-apc-cache-is-full
As of mysql memory table performance, I might have exaggerated a bit ;)

Comment: Sure, thanks, and I rely on the cache. This is why all precaution is taken - automatic checking scripts, plenty of mem - not to overflow the memory allocated to the cache. Memory will *not* be overflowed.